# How to designate a PowerPoint table as a header row with interop?

Tags: excel, accessibility, powerpoint, office-interop, office-automation

I have some formatted data from Excel that I paste into PowerPoint.  It seems like a typical table  but the PowerPoint Accessibility checker warns that it is missing a header row. There is a menu item that converts a row into a header row.  This fixes the warning, but nothing else seems changed. I can't find any properties that seem related to being a header row in the Table, Row, or Cell interfaces. Alt Text isn't involved. What is different with this row/table and how can I do set these properties in interop?